# Animating the height of a page?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with lots of content on. I want to hide the content on page load and then use jquery to animate to the pages height.

I've done a solution with css but it's not elegant. Is there a better way with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can hide your content per default in css

```
#content {
    display: none;
}
```

and show if afterwards using jQuery's `slideDown` which does exactly what you want.

```
$('#content').slideDown(3000); /* 3 seconds */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PcpNk/

Answer (score 0):

```
#divId
{
 height:30px;
 width:400px;
}
```

use jquery animate() function

```
$('#divId').animate({height:'50px'}, 500);
```

for more info check this link [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)